# Change synaptics left touchpad button to middle click on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

So, after upgrading to win10 my synaptics driver didn't work, so I uninstalled and then windows helpfully installed the 'newer' synaptics driver (v19?). However, this driver doesn't seem to have an option to change the touchpad's left mouse button action. I had this set to middle click on windows 8.1 and I really miss it, especially when browsing and middle clicking to open in new tab. Does anyone else do this? Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer to your question, but I use a three-finger click/tap as a middle click for tab browsing.

It might be possible to uninstall the newer driver and install an older one, but can't say for sure.

Comment: [Synaptics_v16_2_21_C_XP32_Vista32_Win7-32_XP64_Vista64_Win7-64_Win8](http://drivers.synaptics.com/Synaptics_v16_2_21_C_XP32_Vista32_Win7-32_XP64_Vista64_Win7-64_Win8.zip) has this functionality and installs ok.